# How to change item drawable color inside layer-list in android

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I've created a drawable file with the below code:

```
    <layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/gray_background"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/light_green"
        android:bottom="@dimen/event_button_bottom_color"/>

</layer-list>
```

Now at run time, I want to change the second item's drawable color (@color/light_green) with some other color programmatically . How can I do that, please help if anyone know how to achieve this.

Thanks a lot in advanced. :)

Comment: One of the solution is you can create another drawable file with same code only keeping another color for second item. Now at run time just change the drawable

Answer (score 6):

First add id for item. Find item by id and change color.

```
<item android:id="@+id/shape_1" android:drawable="@color/gray_background"/>
<item android:id="@+id/shape_2"
    android:drawable="@color/light_green"
    android:bottom="@dimen/event_button_bottom_color"/>
```

Modify at runtime:

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) getResources()
    .getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable);
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable
    .findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.shape_1);
gradientDrawable.setColor(...);
```

Comment: I had to call `view.setBackground(layerDrawable)` for this to take effect. Alternatively, instantiating the `layerDrawable` by `view.getBackground()`  also worked.